# Using Cordova File plugin with Meteor, receive a Code: 5 ENCODING_ERROR in getDirectory() callback

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor, coffeescript, cordova-plugins

I am using Cordova v4.2.0 with Meteor v1.1.0.2 on iOS. I use the FileTransfer plugin (v0.4.3) to download content(images, audio, etc) and the File plugin (v1.3.3) to navigate the filesystem.

When the user downloads the plugin and opens the app for the first time, the content downloads. This works. However, sometimes the user will need to select a new batch of content to download, in which case I must call this function again to download more content. The second time around, I always receive an ENCODING_ERROR when retrieving the content directory using filesystem.root.getDirectory().

```
deferred = Q.defer()
numToLoad = urls.length
numRecieved = 0
urlsToTryAgain = []

onError = (url)->
  return (err)->
    console.log "Error finding file system: "
    console.log err
    deferred.reject(err)

onFileEntrySuccess = (url)->
  return (fileEntry)->
    ft = new FileTransfer()
    endpnt = url.endpointPath()
    uri = encodeURI(endpnt)
    targetPath = fileEntry.toURL()

    ft.onprogress = (event)->
      total = Session.get "total bytes"
      if !total
        total = event.total
        Session.set "total bytes", total
      bytesLoaded = event.loaded
      Session.set "bytes downloaded", bytesLoaded

    onTransferSuccess = (entry)->
      numReceived++
      if numReceived == numToLoad
        deferred.resolve(entry)

    onTransferError = (error)->

     #TIMEOUT_ERROR 
     if error.code == 3
        #try to download the file again
        ft.download(uri, targetPath, onTransferSuccess, onTransferError)
      else
        deferred.reject(error)

    #download the file from the endpoint and save to target path on mobile device
    ft.download(uri, targetPath, onTransferSuccess, onTransferError)


onDirEntrySuccess = (url, directories)->
  return (dirEntry)->
    if directories.length == 0
      file = url.file()
      dirEntry.getFile file, {create: true, exclusive: false}, onFileEntrySuccess(url), onError(file)
    else
      #A branch of the directory tree looks like Content/Image/img.png
      dir = directories[0] + '/'
      remainingDirs = directories.splice(1)
      dirEntry.getDirectory dir, {create: true, exclusive: false}, onDirEntrySuccess(url, remainingDirs), onError(dir)


window.requestFileSystem LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 5*1024*1024, (fs)->
  for url in urls
    #returns an array of the directories, eg ['Content', 'Image']
    directories = url.directories()
    #TODO: this should be done in the object
    firstDir = directories[0] + '/'
    remainingDirs = directories.splice(1)
    #retrieve each directory in the tree one by one, creating it if necessary
    fs.root.getDirectory firstDir, {create: true, exclusive: false}, onDirEntrySuccess(url, remainingDirs), onError(url)
, (err)->
  console.log "ERROR requesting local filesystem: "
  console.log err
  promise.reject err

return deferred.promise
```

I now delete all the local content from the phone before downloading a new batch, ensuring a clean directory for the next batch. However, this did not solve the error.

Any help would be appreciated. Even a lead on what might cause an ENCODING_ERROR would be helpful.

(Before using getDirectory iteratively one directory at a time to move down the tree, I tried simply using fs.root.getFile with the full path to the file target (eg. '/Content/Image/img.png'). However, this always ended in an ABORT_ERROR. This iterative step-wise solution solved that problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it the second I posted this question :p.

I am spinning up a local server to serve the files I've downloaded (because meteor can't access files outside meteor.local). Somehow the localhost url was being appended to the array of directories for each url in the second wave, so instead of ['Content', 'Image'] it was ['http','127.0.0.1:8080', 'Content', 'Image']. Naturally, this caused the ENCODING_ERROR.